# Display result between the period

Tags: sql, between, oraclereports

I am wanting to display results where the date stored in the table is not between the dates specified in the query.

if `last_Tran_date != from_date` 
and if `last_Tran_date != to_date`
therefore there are no transaction.
so i would like to display the result.

example
last transaction date

> 1-JAN-16
>   2-JAN-16
>   8-FEB-16
>   10-MAC-16

**PERIOD TO QUERY**  : (`FROM 2-JAN-16 TO 8-FEB-16`)

IF last transaction date not between the period query, 
then display the result.

```
 SELECT L.TDR_CODE||' - '||T.TDR_NAME TDR_CODE,L.CLIENT_NO,L.CLIENT_TYPE
      ,L.AMLA_RISK,L.ACCT_TYPE,L.CLIENT_NAME,L.DATE_CREATED,L.ANNUAL_INCOME
      ,L.NET_WORTH,L.ACCT_GROUP,L.PAIDUP_CAPITAL,L.SHAREHOLDER_FUND,L.OCCUPATION
      ,L.LAST_TRAN_DATE,K.CHQ_BANK,K.CHQ_NO,K.CHQ_AMT,decode(K.category,'3'
      , decode(nvl(K.cancel_flag,'N'),'N',1,-2) ,0) chqamt_cash 
 FROM BOS_M_CLIENT L
      , BOS_M_TRADER T,BOS_M_LEDGER_REC K 
 WHERE ((K.CHQ_NO IS NOT NULL AND K.CHQ_AMT>50000) 
        OR (K.CATEGORY='3' AND K.CHQ_AMT>10000))
         AND L.PROHIBIT_TRADE<>'C'
         AND L.CLIENT_NO = K.CLIENT_NO(+)
         AND L.amla_risk='High' 
         AND L.TDR_CODE=T.TDR_CODE 
         AND L.tdr_code>=:P_FROM_TDR_CODE 
         AND L.tdr_code<=:P_TO_TDR_CODE 
         AND K.TRAN_DATE>=:P_FROM_DATE 
         AND K.TRAN_DATE<=:P_TO_DATE
         AND L.LAST_TRAN_DATE NOT BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE
```

Comment: The two conditions both seem to be using `NOT BETWEEN`.  Can you add some sample data to your question?

Comment: provide example results

Comment: I am want to display results where the date stored in the table is not between the dates specified in the query.

Comment: @zakira I think you are getting issue with the above query because as I have noticed you  have  missed 'AND' in the last where condition AND L.LAST_TRAN_DATE NOT BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE

Comment: i'm focused on this  'AND L.LAST_TRAN_DATE NOT BETWEEN :P_FROM_DATE AND :P_TO_DATE'

Comment: if i use 'NOT BETWEEN' the result are true for the 1st condition. but after that, i still want display the result within the period for the 2nd after condition 1st.

Comment: make it simple..i want display 'NOT BETWEEN' result in the oracle report.

Comment: Selamat Pagi. I answered your other question just now.  This question is harder to answer but I will try.

Answer (score 0):

**If** there are "**gaps**" in your data then SQL will NOT display the missing data UNLESS you do something extra. e.g.

```
trans_date
2016-01-01
         -- there is a "gap" here, there are "missing dates" 
2016-01-12
```

What you now need is a set of rows for each date from 1-Jan to 12-Jan. There are many way to get those rows, below I have used "connect by leve;" which is an Oracle specific technique and demonstrates how we can find "missing dates":

> ```
> CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE
>     (TRANS_DATE date);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (TRANS_DATE) VALUES (to_date('2016-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'));
> INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (TRANS_DATE) VALUES (to_date('2016-01-12','yyyy-mm-dd'));
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>       c.cal_date, t.*
> FROM (
>       SELECT to_date('2016-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + ROWNUM - 1 as cal_date
>       FROM (
>         SELECT ROWNUM FROM (
>             SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
>             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('2016-01-12','yyyy-mm-dd') - (to_date('2016-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')-1))
>             )
>          )
>       ) c
> LEFT JOIN yourtable t ON c.cal_date = t.trans_date
> WHERE t.trans_date IS NOT NULL
> ORDER BY c.cal_date
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> CAL_DATE  | TRANS_DATE
> :-------- | :---------
> 01-JAN-16 | 01-JAN-16 
> 12-JAN-16 | 12-JAN-16
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>       c.cal_date, t.*
> FROM (
>       SELECT to_date('2016-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd') + ROWNUM - 1 as cal_date
>       FROM (
>         SELECT ROWNUM FROM (
>             SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
>             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('2016-01-12','yyyy-mm-dd') - (to_date('2016-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')-1))
>             )
>          )
>       ) c
> LEFT JOIN yourtable t ON c.cal_date = t.trans_date
> WHERE t.trans_date IS NULL
> ORDER BY c.cal_date
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> CAL_DATE  | TRANS_DATE
> :-------- | :---------
> 02-JAN-16 | null      
> 03-JAN-16 | null      
> 04-JAN-16 | null      
> 05-JAN-16 | null      
> 06-JAN-16 | null      
> 07-JAN-16 | null      
> 08-JAN-16 | null      
> 09-JAN-16 | null      
> 10-JAN-16 | null      
> 11-JAN-16 | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e6321723596b4586adf6620821a24fa)*